# SQL Server: The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted

Tags: sql-server

> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> A connection was successfully established with the server,
> but then an error occurred during the login process.
> (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain
> was issued by an authority that is not trusted.)
> (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -2146893019)
>
> Error Number: -2146893019
> Severity: 20
> State: 0
>
> Program Location:
>
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.SNIWritePacket(SNIHandle handle, SNIPacket packet, UInt32& sniError, Boolean canAccumulate, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock)   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.WriteSni(Boolean canAccumulate) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.WritePacket(Byte flushMode, Boolean canAccumulate) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TdsLogin(SqlLogin rec, FeatureExtension requestedFeatures, SessionData recoverySessionData, FederatedAuthenticationFeatureExtensionData fedAuthFeatureExtensionData, SqlClientOriginalNetworkAddressInfo originalNetworkAddressInfo) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.Login(ServerInfo server, TimeoutTimer timeout, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover, Boolean isFirstTransparentAttempt, Boolean disableTnir) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, ServerCertificateValidationCallback serverCallback, ClientCertificateRetrievalCallback clientCallback, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, SqlClientOriginalNetworkAddressInfo originalNetworkAddressInfo, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
> at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open(SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio.Explorer.ObjectExplorerService.ValidateConnection(UIConnectionInfo ci, IServerType server)
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.ConnectionDlg.Connector.ConnectionThreadUser()

Connect to SQL Server properly

Comment: which client are you using to connect? Are you connecting to a local instance of sql server?

Comment: @derpirscher I was connecting to the local instance. I came across this issue first time because I rarely use the SQL Server. Thank you so much for your response.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For SQL Developer 2019

- Open SQL Server Management Studio
- Select the instance of your choice
- Click on the options
- Go to the connection properties
- Select the "Trust Server Certificate"
- Click on connect

  [image]

Answer (score 5):

Try adding TrustServerCertificate=True; to your connection string.

Comment: This worked for me. Although I also did what @Larnu has answered, but I was still getting the same error. Do you mind explaining the reason for this error.