How to connect ASP.NET Core Web API with SQL Server database in containers
How can I connect to a SQL Server database in an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API ? Both are running in a separate docker containers. I use EF and when I try use migration do create tables, the application exits with an error:
2024-04-03 00:54:47    at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in /src/TagManage.API/Program.cs:line 33
2024-04-03 00:54:47 ClientConnectionId:bfcd1a2f-d4e3-4b6e-87a2-6a419909c5f8
2024-04-03 00:54:47 Error Number:-2146893019,State:0,Class:20

I set my connection string in appsettings.json file:
{
  "JwtSettings": {
    "Issuer": "testIssuer",
    "Audience": "testAudience",
    "SecretKey": "testKeyVERY!SECRET!zaq1@WSX"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "LocalConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=TagManageDb;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;TrustServerCertificate=True",
    "DockerConnection": "Server=db-;Database=TagManageDb;User Id=sa;Password=zaq1@WSX;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }
}

My docker-compose.yml:
version: '3.7'

services:
  db:
    image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest"
    environment:
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
      SA_PASSWORD: "zaq1@WSX"
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
  api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: TagManage.API/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "5000:80"

From what I read this should be enough for running with docker-compose up -d 2 containers and they should be able to connect. There is code to use migration. This works on the local database.
var app = builder.Build();

using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var services = scope.ServiceProvider;

    var context = services.GetRequiredService<AppDbContext>();

    if (context.Database.GetPendingMigrations().Any())
    {
        context.Database.Migrate();
    }
}


Post the full error and not just the highlights

If we assume connection string "DockerConnection" is what is being used, there needs to be a host called db- which has SQL Server running on it and I doubt very much there is. Have you tried Server=localhost or Server=127.0.0.1 in your connection string?

The error seems to be "trust" issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75499536/sql-server-the-certificate-chain-was-issued-by-an-authority-that-is-not-trusted
Try adding TrustServerCertificate=True; to your connection string.

Aside... (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB cannot work in a Docker container, it's a Windows-specific technology for the SQL Server Express with the LocalDB feature.

Aside... the SA_PASSWORD environment variable has been deprecated for quite a while now, you should be using MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD as per the mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server documentation.

Assuming the code in your Docker container has logic to select the "DockerConnection" connection string then Server=db-; will need to be either Server=db; to match the database container's name or Server=host.docker.internal; to connect via the port published on the Docker host.

@F.Kam you were right. TrustServerCertificate=True solved problem, but then program was missing libgssapi_krb5.so.2. After change Trusted_Connection=false everything was fine.

You could try let both container join the same network ("backend") and give the db aliases name "dbcontainer", then you could connect with "Server=dbcontainer;Database=TagManageDb;User Id=sa;Password=zaq1@WSX;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
version: '3.7'

networks:
  backend:
    driver: bridge

services:
  db:
    image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest"
    environment:
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
      SA_PASSWORD: "zaq1@WSX"
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    networks:
      backend:
        aliases:
          - dbcontainer
  api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: TagManage.API/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "5000:80"
    networks:
      backend:

